# unicode error when loading pre-trained model from transformers

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I would like to use the pre-trained model for wav2vec, I have downloaded the model from the [link](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/tree/main/examples/wav2vec)

```
tokenizer = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained('./wav2vec_small_960h.pt')
```

But I got the unicode error:

```
File "/Users/haochen/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error may suggest that you have file which doesn't use `UFT-8` but other encoding - ie. `Latin1`,`CP1250`, etc.

Comment: code `b'\x80'.decode('cp1250')` gives `'€'` - so you may have text in `CP1250` (which is popular in WIndows)

Comment: i think you have to lookup what your loading but transformers loads up a folder path not a pt file, plus for the processor part does not work with pt file